# Call function repeatedly after click

Tags: jquery, refresh

What's wrong with my code, when all I want is to call a function on click and then again repeating every 5 seconds?

```
$("#ref").on("click", ".mc", function(event) {
   var ref_id = $(this).attr('ref_id');
      return getRef(ref_id);
      window.setInterval(function(ref_id){
       getRef(ref_id);
      }, 5000);
});
```

and how can I remove the setInterval on a secondary click?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code

Your code is never reaching the call to `setInterval`, because your

```
return getRef(ref_id);
```

line ends the function.

> how can I remove the setInterval on a secondary click?

By remembering whether you have one running. `setInterval` returns a "timer handle," which is a number that isn't `0`, which you can use to turn it off. So you can use a variable, initialized to `0`, to remember whether you have a timer running (and to remember the handle so you can turn it off):

```
(function() {
    // A handle for setInterval, 0 = not set
    var timer = 0;

    $("#ref").on("click", ".mc", function(event) {
       if (timer) {
          // Timer is set, cancel it
          clearInterval(timer);
          timer = 0;
       }
       else {
          // Timer is not set, set it
          var ref_id = $(this).attr('ref_id');
          // No `return` on the next line, it ends the function
          getRef(ref_id);
          timer = window.setInterval(function(ref_id){
             getRef(ref_id);
          }, 5000);
       }

       // If you need to return something from the click (for instance,
       // `false`), do so here
    });
})();
```

In the above I've assumed you don't want to call `getRef` at all when you're stopping the timer.

Comment: A great answer, thanks! I have several links for calling that function and I want to cancel all the "others" when a new link is clicked, so only 1 interval is "active". It would be the easiest to store the timer-reference in a variable and overwrite it on another call, right?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger: Yes, a variable all of the event handlers have access to. Just be sure you cancel the previous timer before starting another and assigning it to `timer`.

Comment: thank you! That was actually very simple, store the timer value in a global, check if it's there and if it is, cancel before setting the new one. Great!

Comment: @RaphaelJeger: No worries. :-) I'd avoid actually creating a *global*, but just make sure it's a varible all of the event handlers have access to. For instance, in my example above, just define the other event handlers within the anonymous function I've wrapped around the code. Then all the handlers have access to `timer`, but `timer` isn't actually a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `return getRef(ref_id);` in your function is ignored.

You probably should remove the `return` keyword.

Comment: omg I'm such a fool :) I have a return false in getRef but that should go to the end of this function, now that I use it like that :) Thanks!